# Mixing distribution.

Tags: probability, special-functions, lebesgue-measure

Let $\theta$ in $[0,1]$ and defined for $u,v\in [0,1]$,

$$C_\theta (u,v)=\begin{cases}\min(u.v),&&|v-u|\ge \theta\\
 \max(u+v-1,0), && |u+v-1|\ge 1-\theta\\
(u+v-\theta)/2,&& other,\end{cases}$$

Let $P_\alpha$ the measure given by $x^\alpha$ for $\alpha >0$.Define

$$C'(u.v)=\int C_{\theta}(u,v)P_\alpha (d\theta),$$

show that

$$C'(u,v)=\max (u+v-1,0)+ \frac{1}{2(\alpha+1)}\left\{[1-|u+v-1|]^{\alpha+1}-|u-v|^{\alpha+1}\right\}.$$

Sorry I can't see how even begin this. There are a lot cases to check and I'm not sure how to integrate with respect to $P_\alpha$. Are there other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my incomplete try (my definition is probably wrong and seems not getting the answer)

$$ \begin{align} &~ C'(u,v) \\
= &~\int_0^1 C_{\theta}(u,v)\theta^{\alpha}d\theta \\
= &~\int_0^{|v-u|} \min(u,v)\theta^{\alpha}d\theta 
+ \int_{|v-u|}^{1-|u+v-1|} \max(u+v-1,0)\theta^{\alpha}d\theta 
+ \int_{1-|u+v-1|}^1 \frac {u+v-\theta} {2}\theta^{\alpha}d\theta \\
= &~ \min(u,v)\frac {|v-u|^{\alpha + 1}} {\alpha + 1}
+ \max(u+v-1,0)\frac {(1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+1}-|v-u|^{\alpha+1} } {\alpha + 1}\\
&~ + \frac {u+v} {2} \frac {1 - (1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+1}} {\alpha + 1}
- \frac {1 - (1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+2}} {2(\alpha + 2)} \\
= &~ \frac {|v-u|^{\alpha + 1}} {\alpha + 1} 
\left[\min(u,v)-\max(u+v-1,0)\right] \\
&~ + \frac {(1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+1}} {\alpha + 1}
\left[\max(u+v-1,0)-\frac {u+v} {2}\right] \\
&~ + \frac {u+v} {2(\alpha+1)} - \frac {1 - (1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+2}} {2(\alpha + 2)} \\
\end{align}$$

Now we make use of the fact that
$$ \min(u,v) = \frac {u+v - |v-u|} {2}, \max(u+v-1,0) = \frac {u+v-1+|u+v-1|} {2}$$

So we have

$$ \begin{align} &~ C'(u,v) \\
= &~ \frac {|v-u|^{\alpha + 1}} {\alpha + 1} 
\left[\frac {1 - |u+v-1| - |v-u|} {2}\right] 
 - \frac {(1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+2}} {2(\alpha + 1)} \\
&~ + \frac {u+v} {2(\alpha+1)} 
- \frac {1 - (1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+2}} {2(\alpha + 2)} \\
= &~ \frac {|v-u|^{\alpha + 1}(1 - |u+v-1|) - |v-u|^{\alpha + 2}} 
{2(\alpha + 1)} 
- \frac {(1-|u+v-1|)^{\alpha+2}} {2(\alpha + 1)(\alpha+2)}\\
&~ + \frac {u+v} {2(\alpha+1)} - 
\frac {1} {2(\alpha + 2)} \\
\end{align}$$